# change column to row in gridcontrol wpf devexpress

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress, gridcontrol

i have a devexpress gridcontrol ,which displays the data from the sql database.
By default,the table in gridcontrol is coming in a column fashion,
Whereas i need to convert column header as row header, where the column data will be presented as row data.

I have seen a lot of forums and blogs but didn't found any helpful material which helps my condition,
Kindly suggest me the way to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devex has a vertical grid that does exactly that but sadly it is not available for WPF but only for WinForms.

[This link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4630) shows an example of how to show a grid that will resemble the WinForms VerticalGrid control.
[This link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q411353) is to a question on the Devex site that sounds similar to yours. Maybe you'll find an answer there.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks E.T.(One of my favorite movies)
I really needed that information ... :) :)
My application is in wpf so i cant switch to winforms..
Again thanks for the Info ... :)

Comment: NP :) take a look at the links. They're WPF oriented!